# are integer-indexed arrays in BASH space efficient when sparse?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, hashtable, space-complexity

In the `man` page for `bash 5.0.7`, there is a sentence that says

> There is no maximum limit on the size of an array, nor any requirement that members be indexed or assigned  contiguously.

That means I can do things like this:

```
bash $ foo=
bash $ foo[34]=hello
bash $ foo[182]=world
bash $ echo ${foo[34]} ${foo[182]}
hello world
```

I couldn't find any information in the official man pages nor online about the space complexity of arrays like this when they are sparse. If I initialize an array at element 381425381 or something, certainly the internal implementation will store the data in a hash table and not allocate 381425380 spaces beneath it? That seems like the reasonable choice; if this is correct, is there some documentation anywhere that would confirm this is how it's implemented?

Comment: There are bash [sources](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/array.c#L2).

Answer (score 0):

From a [mirror of bash](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/array.c), it appears that

> Arrays are sparse doubly-linked lists.  An element's index is stored with it.

That means yes, sparse arrays are space-efficient, with only valid indices taking up space.